# How to delete a column of a shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete fields in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12329/how-to-delete-fields-in-qgis)

How to delete a column of a shapefile in QGIS?
The "Delete Column" tool is not highlighted even in editable mode.

Answer (score 4):

Use "Table manager" plug in (Manages attribute table structure). you can delete and insert new field using this plug in.